# Rest API design ( twitter )

Tags: c#, rest, twitter

I want to build a rest API for a project, So currently I am trying to build something using Twitter API.
I have registered a new application on Twitter. I have the following keys after registration

1. Consumer key
2. Consumer secret
3. Request token URL
4. Access token URL
5. Authorize URL
6. Registered OAuth Callback URL

So what are these keys and where do all these fit in a Rest API design considerations

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you designing your own API, or are you writing a client for Twitter's API?

Comment: i want to ultimately write my own api, but first i want to use someones else api to get used to it, so that i can write in a better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are OAuth parameters and the best place to put them is in the Authentication header. See the example in section 5.4.1. here http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#consumer_req_param.

Authentication is an issue completely independent of REST and therefore to answer your question, those parameters you listed have **absolutely nothing** to do with RESTful design.

Comment: oh... these parameters i've seen in most of the rest api...is it possible to create a rest api first and then worry about the authentication...or i need to consider authentication while designing the api

Comment: @taher  Build the api first.  You can add the auth in at any time.

Comment: @Darrel.. i was searching for a good book on Rest, everyone on SO is recommending Restful Web services...but the book is published in 2007...do you know any book which is recent and authorative...or that book is still relevent for REST

Comment: @taher http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596801694 and http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805838

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in patterning your restful API after Twitter's, then I suggest studying the way Twitter has organized their API resources (see the method docs under the links in the right sidebar [here](http://dev.twitter.com/doc)), how they support different resource formats (by changing the extension, like .xml or .json, of the requested resource), how they version the endpoint, and which verbs are supported per resource (for example, how the [oauth/request_token](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/oauth/request_token) method supports both POST and GET methods).

So, study the interface that Twitter produced, ignoring the actual implementation behind it for now, and use it to help answer your design questions. Focus on what you want to expose through your interface. How do you plan to project the objects you expose via the interface? What resource formats will you choose to support? How do you plan to version the service endpoint?

By the way, if you're interested in looking at other restful APIs, you can spelunk around using [apigee](http://apigee.com/); they have a console for Twitter [here](https://apigee.com/console/twitter).

Comment: Yes, Twitterizer is a wrapper for the Twitter API.  It contains an implementation of a Twitter OAuth consumer, not a service provider. That's what I thought you were looking for at first; I removed the line from my answer.